# Inventory opening and closing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

When i press E, to get out of a crafting table or a furnace, it sometimes opens my inventory.
I've figured out that holding E opens and closes it really fast, how do i stop this from happening??

Comment: Does this happen with other keys? (Try binding inventory open to something else in your controls and test it) Does it happen in other games?

Comment: Yeah, when i press others like 'escape' it does the same. Ill check in another game right now

Comment: No, in both terraria and skyrim it doesn't do this.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can use the escape button to exit out of any gui, including any container inventory. I've always used this, so I don't know why Minecraft allowed us to close the container too! (If that makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

By default, you press E to open your inventory. However, you can change this by pressing the Escape key:
[image: Press the Escape key]

Than, click on Options. From there you will be able to open Controls:
[image]

Change your default Inventory key from here.